# JS, как изменить глобальную переменную в данной ситуации

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

```
function (email) {
var ourUser
// Подключение к дб
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "root",
  database: "users",
  port: "3309",
  password: "root"
})
// Запрос в бд
connection.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE login= ?`, email, function (err, result, field) {
  // Структура успешно создаётся, данные заносятся
  ourUser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0]))
  // Закрываем подключение
  connection.end()
})
// В итоге получаем undefind
return ourUser
}
```

Хочу перенести данные (логин, пароль, id) из бд в переменную, а позже вернуть её по результату вычисления функции. Как можно это реализовать(нужно по итогам вычисления функции, вернуть эту структуру наружу фукнции `ourUser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0]))`)?

Comment: Вернуть куда, наружу функции?

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg да

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg то есть через return, как написано изначально в коде, если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, что бы возвращался не undefind, а нужная структура

Comment: И кстати, что это за строка `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать асинхронные функции. Можно конечно и на `callback`-ах, но с ними легче запутаться. `return`-ом такое возвратить нельзя.

```js
async function select(email) {
  // ...
  return new Promise((s, e) => {
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE login= ?`, email, function (err, result, field) {
      connection.end()
      // Эта строка эквивалентна return или throw Error
      err ? e(err) : s(result) 
    })
  })
}

void (async () => {
  let result
  try {
    result = await select(email)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
    return
  }
  // ... Что то делаем дальше
})()
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сейчас достаточно того, что вы сообщили о невозможности возвращения return такого значения.  Здесь `s(result)` обозначает, что в s передаётся результат, правильно?

Comment: Попробовал, всё получилось, огромное спасибо за ответ :)))) Но не могли бы вы ответить на последний вопрос, или подсказать что загуглить, почему при нашем `return s(result)`, `return` возвращается не в функцию `function(err, result, field)`, а в Promise?

Comment: Хотя, видимо я не правильно понял, у нас просто указывается значение для `s` в виде `result`, а не происходит `return`

Comment: @n33t `return`-ом мы уже возвратили `Promise` - обертка для выполнения отложенных операций. Оператор `await` приостанавливает `async`-функцию и дожидается разрешения `Promise`. При вызове `resolve`(у нас это s(...)) `Promise` считается разрешенным. Ранее установленный оператор `await` извлекает результат из `Promise` и передает его переменной.